# Why doesn't my python console recognise new environment variables? (Pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables

As the title says I have added some environment variables to my `.zshrc` file but my python console was unable to recognize them. I assume I have to restart it somehow - how do I do this?

Long solution, quit Pycharm completely and open it back up. Surely there's a neater way?

Tried to click re-run, tried to close the console and re-open it, had to restart Pycharm completely.

Comment: On a console, type `source ~/.zshrc`. That should execute that file, effectively "restarting" the shell, with the new environment variables.

Comment: Or see if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712203/how-to-reinitialize-the-python-console-in-pycharm

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments guys, very new to the software engineering world. Has been educational :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variable are not supposed to be changed at run-time. Think about having a program with threads (like PyCharm). One thread read the variables, and a process will modify the variables. Probably something wrong will happen. But also what doesn't it mean? A process should continuously check language, and change display language if environment change? It would not be nice to program, and very slow for very seldom changes. And for sure there are other reasons. Think also about changing it. Do you need to update it to all children and gran-children? So environment variable are considered fix to a process. A process can set it at start of a child process, but not much more.

Note: shells keeps own list of environmental variables, one *intern* for scripts so with local variables, and one to be set at child creation (the `extern`, and now shell evaluate variables at use (e.g. for prompts).

And your case is different: you change the configuration file (which indirectly change the environment variables). The documentation tell us that such files are *start-up files*, so read only at start-up.

You can source the file, e.g. `. ~/.zshrc` (also `source ~/.zshrc`, which read the file not as batch program (so not as an independent program, so not as a child), but as you typed the program, so modifying the existing shell status (and variables). But as I wrote on the first paragraph: doing so you modify the internal variables (of the shell), not the environmental variables of any children.

Answer (score 0):

As the python console is a child process of pycharm and pycharm's environment won't receive the updates until you restart it, then the environment variables  are not there.

Sourcing the file will work for the terminal but not the python console.